# Creating Class Diagram for Android Application

Tags: java, android, class, uml, class-diagram

Do I include Activities in the class diagram for a Android Application and what are they entity or boundary also do I have to include `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method in the class diagram?

Answer (score 0):

We have just discussed the matter with [chelder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1198404/chelder) for two days.

Here are the results:

[first stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592481/how-to-represent-the-call-to-a-class-through-another-class-using-an-uml-class-di) - trying to create a common picture we moved to component diagram

[second stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689109/uml-class-diagram-how-to-model-relations-about-calling-a-method-or-starting-an) - trying to make something more strict we came to the Composite Structure Diagram

You should use the class diagram only for the classes belonging to one intent.