# What is the difference between a composite pattern expressed with arrow point to component and one without?

Tags: design-patterns, uml, class-diagram, composite

I am designing a program and I would like to make use of the composite pattern. I have noticed that there are two ways of expressing it:
[image: Class diagram of composite pattern with no arrow pointing to the component class]

and

[image: Class diagram of composite pattern with arrow pointing to the component class]

What is the difference between the two? 
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UML Aggregation with and without arrow head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738757/uml-aggregation-with-and-without-arrow-head)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @alper already states there is no real difference between both notations.

The top one allows navigation in both directions (so `Component` can see `Composite` namely as `parent`) while the lower one does not have this navigability. To make make the missing `parent` relation more obvious the author has added the arrow.

So the top one is a more universal implementation of the Composite pattern.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference except that the one with the zero accepts composite objects that are empty and the other one guarantees that a composite object has at least one part.

Comment: thank you for your reply! So the presence of the arrow does not change anything?

Comment: No, I'd say the arrow is superfluous (especially a thin one).

Comment: The arrow is not superfluous. It indicates in which direction you can expect to be able to navigate easily. Missing arrows indicate that the navigability is unspecified.