What is the difference between these relationships in UML?
I have repeatedly seen these relationships in UML diagrams:

What is the difference between the relationships above and the relationships below?

I know what aggregation and composition are, I want to understand the difference between the usual aggregation and composition relationships and arrow relationships. You can also show examples in C#.

You tagged C#. Do you need examples in C#?

The navigability part is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738757/uml-aggregation-with-and-without-arrow-head

@GeertBellekens I think this is the real duplicate, because OP doesn't ask about assoc aggreg compo but navigability on topnof aggreg/compo.

@Christophe when I marked the duplicate, the question was only about the difference between aggregation and composition. The navigability part was added later. But there are loads of other questions that deal with that topic as well.

@GeertBellekens yes, it was not a criticism but a confirmation. no problem, i've added your hint to the dupes, so that duplicate notification is comprehensive for the current version of the question ;-)

Aggregation:
It depicts a "has-a" relationship and represents a whole-part hierarchy where the part can exist independently of the whole.For example, a car and a wheel relationship is an aggregation. A car has wheels, but the wheel can exist without the car.
When you want to express a relationship where one object is a part of another, but it can exist independently.
Car <>---- Wheel

Composition:
It indicates a stronger form of the "has-a" relationship, i.e., a whole-part hierarchy where the part cannot exist independently of the whole.A human has a heart, and the heart cannot exist independently without the human.
When you want to express a relationship where one object is part of another, and it cannot exist independently.
Human <<>>---- Heart

I know what aggregation and composition are. I need to understand the difference between them with an arrow and without an arrow.

Sorry for the missunderstanding on my side. Can you provide an example with arrows? I may have seen both versions (with and without).
